# USPTO part re-submission

Tags: patent-drawings, written-description

I decided to file a utility patent application myself without an attorney after watching hours of boring youtube videos about the patent and patent process (I don't know how you guys stay awake). I filed a US utility patent using EFS-Web myself online and it was smooth. I got a letter from USPTO after a few weeks saying that I -- accidentally -- omitted the description of a single image under the `Description of Drawings`.  I was asked to submit the description for it.  No issue in that regard but my question is that do I resubmit the whole application with the correction, or a sheet of paper with updated `Description of Drawings` section of the application, or just a single paragraph with the description of that single image?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt from [USPTO example](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/web/offices/pac/dapp/opla/preognotice/formatrevamdtprac.pdf). The cross-outs didn't come over in my cut and paste so do look at the link.

> Amendments to the Specification: Please replace paragraph [0021] with
>   the following amended paragraph:
>
> [0021] In the construction of the bucket of this invention, various
>   materials have been selected [[and]] which offer a number of diverse
>   properties [[ , ]] and allow for varied functions of the article.  For
>   caustic solutions, the bucket can be made of a durable polymer plastic
>   material.  Where an aesthetic appeal is desired, the bucket can be any
>   [[of]] one of many attractive colors.  The following listing list of
>   properties serves to define possible uses for the buckets.